# having an exception how to resolve this

Tags: java, android, xml, exception, crash

I am developing android app. I am new to Android and I am developing bluetooth app. My project's having an error when I clicked on button my app crashes and having exception which is given in catalog. Here's the XML layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Bluetooth"
        android:id="@+id/btnBluetooth"
        android:onClick="getBluetoothActivity"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's the code.

```
public void getBluetoothActivity(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BluetoothActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent); //exception
}
```

And the logs,

> 04-15 21:48:24.760 126-332/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Starting activity:
>   Intent { cmp=com.example.app/.BluetoothActivity } from pid 25365
>       04-15 21:48:24.770 25365-25365/com.example.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
>       at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2191)
>       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
>       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9293)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>       at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2186)
>       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
>       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9293)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>       Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class
>   {com.example.app/com.example.app.BluetoothActivity}; have you declared
>   this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>       at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1541)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1515)
>       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2988)
>       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3094)
>       at com.example.app.MainActivity.getBluetoothActivity(MainActivity.java:21)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>       at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2186)
>       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
>       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9293)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I am developing Bluetooth app in Android Studio
when click on button having an exception and app crashes.

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and format your post properly.

Comment: Now check it.i formated this in the readable form

Comment: Read the text of the last "caused by" line and answer that question. Have you done what it asks you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.app/com.example.app.BluetoothActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml`

This means `BluetoothActivity` wasn't declared in your manifest. If you think it already was, then verify your package names are still matching what is declared (`android:name` and `package` in the manifest).

I searched for the phrase "caused by" in your question. That is generally the best way to find where and why exceptions were thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I see your issue. It is nothing major.

You need to remember that you design the XML for your Android Application explicitly.

You are missing a declaration for the button to have a onClick function.

I have fixed it for you below:

---

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">

 <Button
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/Bluetooth"
  android:id="@+id/btnBluetooth"
  android:onClick="getBluetoothActivity"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_alignParentStart="true" 
                android:onClick="getBluetoothActivity"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Also please ensure that the BluetoothActivity.class has been created within the correct package!

Good luck,

Let me know of the outcome